# how do i animate another colour after this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animated

I have a 2x4 box using a 'div' in html and formatted in CSS. [this](https://jsfiddle.net/flake96/undpef6g/)

```
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="box rightSpacing">
  <!--Box 1--->
</div>
<div class="box rightSpacing" id="green">
  <!--Box 2--->
</div>
<div class="box rightSpacing">
  <!--Box 3--->
</div>
<div class="box">
  <!--Box 4--->
</div>

<div class="box rightSpacing">
  <!--Box 5--->
</div>
<div class="box rightSpacing" id="yellow">
  <!--Box 6--->
</div>
<div class="box rightSpacing">
  <!--Box 7--->
</div>
<div class="box">
  <!--Box 8--->
</div>


</div>

</body>
```

i need to animate in a similar style the 'div id="green"' to a green colour directly after it for a similar length of time. This is where I need help, i'm stuck. thanks

this is the code i have already for the animation in javascript.

```
                lerp = function(a, b, u) {
              return (1 - u) * a + u * b;
            };


            fade = function(element, property, start, end, duration) {
              var interval = 10;
              var steps = duration / interval;
              var step_u = 1.0 / steps;
              var u = 0.0;
              var theInterval = setInterval(function() {
                if (u >= 1.0) {
                  clearInterval(theInterval)
                }
                var r = parseInt(lerp(start.r, end.r, u));
                var g = parseInt(lerp(start.g, end.g, u));
                var b = parseInt(lerp(start.b, end.b, u));
                var colorname = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
                el.style.setProperty(property, colorname);
                u += step_u;
              }, interval);
            };

            el = document.getElementById('yellow');
            property = 'background-color';
            startColor = {
              r: 255,
              g: 255,
              b: 255,
            };
            endColor = {
              r: 255,
              g: 255,
              b: 0
            };
            fade(el, 'background-color', startColor, endColor, 10);



            setTimeout(function() {
              fade(el, 'background-color', endColor, startColor, 10);
            }, 1000);
```

- please bare with as i am extremely new to this!

Comment: How you want to animate that div?

Comment: in the same way i have already. it should operate as the yellow one does. https://jsfiddle.net/flake96/undpef6g/

Comment: I don't see yellow div animated. It just hide after some time without any animation

Comment: oh yeah ive got my words mixed up, I want that to happen again afterwards but with a different div the 'green' one and in a different colour

Comment: Something like. https://jsfiddle.net/undpef6g/1/ ?

Comment: almost, however i would like the green color to happen in another div box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following way.

```
el = document.getElementById('yellow');
el1 = document.getElementById('green');

setTimeout(function() {
    fade(el, 'background-color', endColor, startColor, 10);
    fade(el1, 'background-color', greeColor, startColor, 2000);
}, 1000);
```

And change in function

```
el.style.setProperty(property, colorname);
```

To

```
element.style.setProperty(property, colorname);
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/undpef6g/2/)**

Comment: thank you lovely and what if i wanted to add an extra color in a different box?

Comment: @Joe96 You should add rgb for that. And if in different then you should add div also.

Comment: @Joe96 glad to help. Don't forget to mark it as answer by selecting on right symbol.

Comment: i tried but cant work out how to add it after, if you see it happens at the same time? https://jsfiddle.net/undpef6g/4/